# HTML Tag in Angular Expression

Tags: angularjs, expression

Is there a way around the following in Angular:

```
<span>Delete {{ vm.name ? '<strong>' + vm.name + '</strong> : 'this user'}}?</span>
```

If the `vm.name` exists, I want to wrap the name in `<strong>` tags, if it doesn't I want to display `this user` without `<strong>` tags?

Is this possible?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you use styles? or you need the `<strong>` tag

Comment: I would prefer to use the `<strong>` tag, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<span>Delete <strong ng-if="vm.name">{{vm.name}}</strong><span ng-if="!vm.name">this user</span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways to accomplish this:

#### ng-if

```
<span>
    Delete <strong ng-if="vm.name">vm.name</strong><span ng-if="!vm.name">this user</span>?
</span>
```

This will show `<strong ng-if="vm.name">vm.name</strong>` if `vm.name` exists, and `<span ng-if="!vm.name">this user</span>` if they do not.

#### conditional classes

```
<style>
   .bold {
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>

<span>
    Delete <span ng-class="{bold: vm.name}">{{ vm.name ? vm.name : 'this user'}}</span>?
</span>
```

This will conditionally add the class `bold` to your span. You need to add your own CSS to that class (unless it exists already).

There's also something you can do with `ng-bind-html`, but it's a bit of a pain and I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

There could be different ways to achieve this.

Option  1

```
<span > Delete <strong>{{asset.Name}} </strong> <span ng-if=asset.Name.length==0> this user</span></span>
```

option 2

```
<span ng-if="asset.Name==0">  Delete  this user</span>
<span ng-if="asset.Name.length>0"> Delete <strong>{{asset.Name}} </strong>
```